# Modal doesn't close when close button is pressed in laravel application

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4

Here is the modal code:

Modal opening button(It **wouldn't work** either if I used **button** tag insted of **a-href** tag):

```
     <a href="" class="btn btn-primary" title="View Data" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">
<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
</a>
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">Large modal</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4>Overflowing text to show scroll behavior</h4>
                <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded text-left" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

The surprising fact is the **modal neither opens nor closes** when I use **Buttons** but everything *works perfectly* *when I use* **a href** tag like-

```
<a href="" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded text-left" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
```

While using button it says: The following data would have been submitted to the server: ...
[image]

Why is the reason for this strange behavior?

Comment: Hi. I think you probably used that `button` in an HTML `form`. Every `button` in a `form` are supposed as a submit button, so if you press the `button` it will submit the `form`. You must prevent submitting `form` by the `button`. [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: @Ahmad_kh I'm certain that it doesn't have any form. I'm just showing some data from the database in this modal.